# How do I make the 'ilovepdf' API not think my PDF is 'blank'?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script in Google Drive to automate the process of stripping images out of PDFS that arrive in my email.

I am using an external API 'ilovepdf' to assist with this.

Everything works fine, EXCEPT no matter what PDF I try upload, the api rejects it saying:

> {"error":{"type":"ProcessingError","message":"This task can't be
>   processed. Check why in the
>   params.","code":400,"param":{"files":["Files cannot be blank."]}}}

The PDFs I am uploading are not blank!  Help, please!

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {


  // (1) Request signed token

  var apiUrl_auth = 'https://api.ilovepdf.com/v1/auth'

  var data_auth =  {
            public_key: '**REMOVED FROM PUBLIC VIEWING***'
        }

  var options_auth = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'payload' : data_auth,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  }

  var response_auth = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl_auth, options_auth)

  var longtoken = response_auth.getContentText()

  Logger.log(longtoken)
  Logger.log('STEP 1, Authentication and token collection complete')

  var token = longtoken.substring(10)


  // (2) Retrieve the information of which server will be our assigned server and what Task ID we need to use

  var apiUrl_start = 'https://api.ilovepdf.com/v1/start/pdfjpg'

  var header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}

  var options_start = {
    'method' : 'GET',
    'headers' : header,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  }

  var response_start = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl_start, options_start)

  var response_start_text = response_start.getContentText()

  Logger.log(response_start_text)
  Logger.log('STEP 2, Server and TASKID retrival complete')

  var server = response_start_text.substring(11,28)

  var taskID = response_start_text.substring(38,192)


  // (3) Upload the files

  var apiUrl_upload = 'https://' + server + '/v1/upload'

  var DRIVE_PDF_FILE = DriveApp.getFilesByName('temp.pdf')
  var DRIVE_PDF_NAME = 'temp.pdf' 

  var payload_upload =  {
    task: taskID,
    file: DRIVE_PDF_FILE.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF),
        }

  var options_upload = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'headers' : header,
    'payload' : payload_upload,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  }

  var response_upload = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl_upload, options_upload)

  var response_upload_text = response_upload.getContentText()

  Logger.log(response_upload_text)
  Logger.log('STEP 3, Uploading complete')

  var server_file_name = response_upload_text.substring(19, 88)



  // (4) Process the files

  var apiUrl_process = 'https://' + server + '/v1/process'

  var processing_files = {
    '[server_filename]' : server_file_name,
    '[filename]' : DRIVE_PDF_NAME, 
  }

  var payload_process =  {
    task : taskID,
    tool : 'pdfjpg',
    files : processing_files,
   }

  var options_process = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'headers' : header,
    'payload' : payload_process,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  }

  var response_process = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl_process, options_process)

  var response_process_text = response_process.getContentText()

  Logger.log(response_process_text)
  Logger.log('STEP 4, Processing complete')


    // (XX) Get info about the uploaded file

  var apiUrl_info = 'https://' + server + '/v1/task/' + taskID

  var options_info = {
    'method' : 'GET',
    'headers' : header,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  }

  var response_info = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl_info, options_info)

  var response_info_text = response_info.getContentText()

  Logger.log(response_info_text)
  Logger.log('info collected')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please be sure processing_files is an array

```
var processing_files = {
    '[server_filename]' : server_file_name,
    '[filename]' : DRIVE_PDF_NAME, 
}
```

The error is saying that the parameter files is 'empty' or is not an array. Not that the PDF itself is empty.

Best regards!